# How to write a responsive css for all devices?

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-resolution

Hi I need to write `css` that supports all device. This is not a new question but I am still confused what to do. 
I tried with media query like this

```
@media screen and (device-width:1080px)
{
    div::before
    {
        content: url('6plus.jpg');
    }
}
@media screen and (device-width:750px)
{
    div::before
    {
        content: url('6.jpg');
    }
}
```

Above code is specific with device width. This looks fine but when I design for all devices this grabs lot of time. I am really confused with `min,max in media query and -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`. I am trying this with image with iphone 6 and 6plus resolution. What image should I use and what should be the resolution.
How could I use media queries in better way that supports all device. Can someone help me?

Comment: You might get a good answer here, but there are **loads** of great articles on the web about `@media` rules - I would suggest giving those a read. [Here's one](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and [another](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) and [here's are some of the most popular breakpoints](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries). I think you're question might be a bit *broad*

Comment: use relative units media query will be only required if none works(except some like for menu bars) here's demo it resize according to window   https://jsbin.com/wiriduwotu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thank you...What image should I use and it should be of what resolution. I saw many websites but I could not understand @Quoid

Comment: @Anu I am not sure I understand; but if you are curious about different image resolutions, for different devices, [read about that here](http://www.mightybytes.com/blog/make-retina-images-website/) - hope this helps

Comment: I will make my question short and clear. I am working with mobile app with fixed size.I am not able to fix it within my mobile device. @Quoid